# Are "git pull" and "git checkout -b" safe operations?

Tags: git

I have been using git for 8 months now and I just hit an interesting issue where untracked files seemed to vanish on me without any warning. Here is the pastebin of my console:

http://pastebin.com/membm34J

The files that vanished are:

- src/API/ConfigurationFileReader.java
- src/API/testConfigPull.java

As you will see, they are visible when the first "status" call is made. Are these files gone forever? I am not sure what I did to make them disappear.

Comment: Thank you! I was quite worried for the past 10 minutes.

Comment: Also, they didn't "vanish"... they're in your working directory.

Comment: Yes... I see that now. Could you post your explanation in the answer section so I can count this as "solved"? Currently, I am just telling people to look at your comment which feels pretty sloppy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gradle/2.6/
        .idea/
        .settings/gradle.prefs
       GameCentricsAWS.iml
       GameCentricsAWS2.iml
       src/                                       *** here ***
       tmpLibs/
```

Git is telling you that the entire src/` directory  is untracked, which includes your files in question.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. The new class files I created were put into a src/ directory. Not sure if I did that or if Eclipse did some auto-class-placing on me. Thank you!